# Small dataset results in regression tree with only 1 terminal node

Tags: cart

I don't understand why this decision tree has only one terminal node:

```
library(tree)

x1 = c(-10, -9, -11, -11, 0, 1, 0, 0)
x2 = c(-9, -11, -10, -11, 0, 0, 1, 0)
y = c(-50, -50.1, -50, -50, 8, 8, 7.9, 8)
df = data.frame(x1=x1, x2=x2, y=y)

t <- tree(y ~ ., df)
summary(t)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dataset is too small to split the nodes per the default control parameters of `tree()`. Admittedly, getting this out of `?tree` requires digging additionally into `?tree.control`. You can reduce the minimum number of data points per node and the minimum number per *child* node like this:

```
t <- tree(y ~ ., df,
    control=tree.control(nobs=nrow(df),mincut=4,minsize=8))
```

This gives you a tree with two terminal nodes.